# How can do view a .h5ad file format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, format-specifiers

Am working on MARS implementation, I've run the code but I can't view the output since it's in .h5ad format. I've tried running the code with google colab but still can't find the solution

To run .h5ad file and implement MARS source code

Comment: Did you search before asking the question? When I search for "h5ad" on Google, the first result is [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/scverse/anndata/issues/180) that points to [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/).